# Parsing JSON response using Codable in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I will receive an API response as JSON with array of objects. For example,

```
{
        "Header": "Verification",
        "Info": [
            {
                "mobile": "**** **** 123"
            },
            {
                "email": "s******k**@g***.com"
            }
        ],
}
```

I used Codable feature and created a Struct like the following,

```
struct cResponse: Codable 
{
  var Header: String?
  var Info: [Info] 
}

struct Info: Codable {
  var mobile: String!
  var email: String!
}
```

I am trying to decode the JSON response by using JSONDecoder in swift like below code,

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let decodedcRES: cResponse = try decoder.decode(cResponse.self, from: CData)
```

This is working fine untill Info from server is only mobile and email.

But Info will be dynamic at runtime (i.e) I will receive more JSON Objects under Info from server. So if i create a Struct like the following,

```
struct cResponse: Codable 
{
  var Header: String?
  var Info: [String] 
}
```

i am receiving "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." as error .

How can i handle the dynamic JSON array objects in swift with Codable feature?

Comment: Info is an array of objects, not an array of string

Comment: Rather than `error.localizedDescription` print the `error` instance. It tells you exactly what's wrong. And never never ever declare members in a struct which is going to be decoded with `Decodable` as implicit unwrapped optional. And name properties and variables always lowercased to avoid a potential namespace clash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info key contains array of object, so change your struct to:

```
struct cResponse: Codable
{
    var Header: String?
    var Info: [[String: String]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Previously i used [String : Any] for Info. Now i used [String: String] and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @user7413163 Any doesn't conform to codable protocol by default, so you need to implement the encode and decode methods.

Answer (score 0):

`Info` is array of objects, so you can make something like this to parse it.

```
struct cResponse: Codable 
{
  var Header: String?
  var Info: [[String : String]] 
}
```

Comment: You forget to implement `CodingKeys` enum & `init(decoder: Decoder)` to parse the `mobile/email` value.

Answer (score -1):

A better approach is to use a Custom enum as a Decodable :

```
enum ContactType: Decodable {
    case email(String)
    case mobile(String)
    case unknown
    enum MyKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case email
        case mobile
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: MyKeys.self)
        if let emailString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email) {
            self = .email(emailString)
        } else if let mobileString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .mobile) {
            self = .mobile(mobileString)
        } else {
            self = .unknown
        }
    }
}
```